# Return path empty, therefore, dynamic SPF lookups based on client HELO domain?

Tags: postfix

My mail server is setup with the domain example.com. I created a subdomain lists.example.com which is an CNAME to my example.com. My example.com has a valid SPF, DMARC and DKIM when I email from example.com. Everything is fine then since the CNAME gets the same values, which are just as valid since the IPs in the SPF don't need any changes, all runs on the same server.

I have another domain called example.org. Also has a valid SPF, DMARC and DKIM. Both domains allow themselves to be valid senders. In addition to that, I added the IPs of both servers in each other's SPF, just to make sure it's not that. I know it's not needed.

In my virtual aliases maps I have the following.

```
admins@lists.example.com user@example.org
```

So in other words, mail coming in on admins@lists.example.com is forwarded to an external domain (example.org). Now, here it becomes interesting. It works fine if I forward mail within my own example.com, e.g. user@example.com. But when I forward it to example.org, for some reason the return path is empty. And because of that, it probably uses the HELO domain of the client to check the SPF. When I mail from an other domain (let's say example.uk.co) it checks the SPF record of example.uk.co if it's a valid sender for lists.example.com. Which it's not of course. When I do add it, I receive the email just fine. But now the SPF lookup seems dynamic, so when I mail from gmail, it checks the SPF of gmail. When sending the mail from gmail I don't get a postmaster message on example.uk.co. So there isn't somewhere a routing config to my other mail server. Because otherwise I would always receive these postmaster messages, but it only happens with I email to admins@lists.example.com from a domain where I do get to see the postmaster emails, because I administrator those domains. I don't see them for gmail and alike.

I base these conclusions on this.

- https://knowledge.ondmarc.redsift.com/en/articles/1739881-spf-record-troubleshooting-and-top-tips
- http://www.open-spf.org/action_browse_id_FAQ/Common_mistakes_revision_26/#helo

Unless I misread those explanations of course. But my lists.example.com does have an SPF, because it's a CNAME from example.com.

I specify the MX domain explicitly because my spf is in _spf.example.com, this makes sure I get the right IP from the DNS lookup. And for additional setup I added the A/AAAA record of example.org, just to make sure it's not that. example.org also has the IP of example.com, just to rule that bit out.

```
v=spf1 exp=explain.%{d} +mx:example.com +a:example.org -all
```

So, my guess is that this problem happens because the return path is empty. Could it be something else? Does anyone know how to solve this?

My virtual aliases maps file:

```
admins@lists.example.com user@example.org
```

My virtual mailbox domains:

```
example.com OK
lists.example.com OK
```

My main.cf:

```
canonical_maps = hash:$config_directory/canonical
compatibility_level = 3.6
delay_warning_time = 1d
disable_vrfy_command = yes
enable_long_queue_ids = yes
inet_interfaces = localhost, 1.2.3.4
lmtp_tls_protocols = >=TLSv1.3
maximal_queue_lifetime = 5w
message_size_limit = 50000000
milter_default_action = accept
mydomain = example.com
myhostname = mx1.$mydomain
mynetworks = localhost
myorigin = $mydomain
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
policyd-spf_time_limit = 1h
recipient_delimiter = +
relocated_maps = hash:$config_directory/relocated
smtp_dns_support_level = dnssec
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
smtp_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers = EXP, LOW, MEDIUM, aNULL, eNULL, SRP, PSK, kDH, DH, kRSA, DHE, DSS, RC4, DES, IDEA, SEED, ARIA, CAMELLIA, AESCCM8, 3DES, ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384, ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256, ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384, ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256, MD5, SHA
smtp_tls_security_level = dane
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:$data_directory/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
smtpd_client_auth_rate_limit = 20
smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit = 20
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 20
smtpd_client_new_tls_session_rate_limit = 20
smtpd_client_recipient_rate_limit = 20
smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_unknown_client_hostname permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_etrn_restrictions = permit_mynetworks reject
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks reject_invalid_helo_hostname
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891 inet:localhost:8893
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_invalid_helo_hostname reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname reject_unknown_recipient_domain reject_unlisted_recipient reject_unauth_pipelining permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination reject_rhsbl_helo dbl.spamhaus.org reject_rhsbl_reverse_client dbl.spamhaus.org reject_rhsbl_sender dbl.spamhaus.org reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf      check_policy_service inet:localhost:10023 check_policy_service inet:localhost:2223
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_login_maps = $virtual_alias_maps
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain reject_non_fqdn_sender
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/smtp.$mydomain/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = $config_directory/dh/2023-04.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/smtp.$mydomain/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:$data_directory/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes
tls_medium_cipherlist = ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
tls_ssl_options = NO_COMPRESSION NO_RENEGOTIATION
unknown_address_reject_code = 554
unknown_client_reject_code = 554
unknown_hostname_reject_code = 554
virtual_alias_maps = hash:$config_directory/virtual_alias
virtual_gid_maps = static:997
virtual_mailbox_base = /srv/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = hash:$config_directory/virtual_mailbox_domains
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:$config_directory/virtual_mailbox
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_uid_maps = static:997
```

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly you're running a mailing list? In that case you need to perform sender rewriting so that messages sent by your system on behalf of other users actually appear to originate from your system and not theirs

Comment: @roaima that sounds like the problem I have and a possible solution. Do you have an example of such a rewrite? I've checked these options: https://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#overview But I can't really say with certainty which one I should use, smtp_generic_maps?

Comment: I'm not a Postfix expert so I can't give you an answer here, but [SRS / Sender Rewriting when forwarding mail through postfix](https://serverfault.com/q/82234/267016) and [Forwarding to Gmail account via Postfix: SPF record with a hard fail](https://serverfault.com/a/1120558/267016), both over on [SF], look like they're what you're after

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is with the emails being sent to the admins@lists.example.com address is because the return path is empty. This causes the SPF check to use the HELO domain of the client when sending the email, which is not always a valid sender for lists.example.com. To solve the issue, you may need to update the configuration of your email server to ensure that the return path is properly set for emails forwarded from lists.example.com to example.org. Without more information about your specific email server setup, it's difficult to provide more specific guidance.

Comment: Hi, this is exactly my conclusion that I describe in my topic here. I have provided my mail server setup in terms of SPF, DNS and Postfix configuration. What information are you missing?

Comment: The issue may be related to the return path being empty, but it's hard to say without additional information about the problem and the error message.

Based on your provided configuration files, some things to check include:

Ensure that the domains and addresses specified in the virtual alias maps file are correct and are valid.
Verify that the virtual mailbox domains are set up correctly.
Ensure that the smtpd_sender_login_maps value is set to the correct value for your virtual alias maps file.
You may need to check the logs for more specific error messages and debug information.

Comment: As mentioned in the topic, it works fine when I add the IP of example.co.uk in the SPF. But that should not be the fix, because then you have to include the whole world to make it work, which makes no sense. `smtpd_sender_login_maps` is set to the default value `$virtual_alias_maps`. I can verify my hypothesis that this has to do with the empty return path. Some suggestions on how to correctly set that would be greatly appreciated, then I can test that. The logs say what I've explained, based on the HELO domain an SPF is done and the mail delivery fails at that point.

Comment: The return-path in an email is the address that the bounce messages are sent to. An empty return-path can cause the email to fail SPF validation because the SPF record is not able to determine the source of the email.

To correct this issue, you can specify a return-path in your mailSR configuration. Here's an example of how to set it in Postfix:`sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_bcc`.
In this example, the return-path is set using the sender_bcc maps file,which contains a list of sender email addresses and their bounce email addresses.This  should resolve the SPF validation issue.

Comment: It seems a bit odd to use the BCC maps for that, do you have a source where this is explained as a solution?